# How to move root node under new node in yq?

Tags: yq

In [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), how do you move the root node under a new parent node? For example,

```
yq '...' <<<'hello: world'
```

Gives the following output:

```
$ yq '...' <<<'hello: world'
cat:
  dog:
    hello: world
```

As a workaround, I assign the root node to a new `tmp` root node, then filter out—see below. But I wonder if there is a better way.

```
$ yq '. as $root | .tmp.cat.dog = $root | .tmp' <<<'hello: world'
cat:
  dog:
    hello: world
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do you move the root node under a new parent node?

You can simply create the new document with a reference to the input context `.` (see [Wrap (prefix) existing object](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/create-collect-into-object#wrap-prefix-existing-object) in the manual):

```bash
yq '{"cat":{"dog":.}}' <<< 'hello: world'
```

If you want to preserve the `.cat.dog` path expression notation, you can start off with an empty object `{}` instead of using a placeholder like `.tmp`:

```bash
yq '. as $root | {} | .cat.dog = $root' <<< 'hello: world'
```

Output:

```yaml
cat:
  dog:
    hello: world
```

Comment: Excellent answer! Especially thank you for referencing the accurate documentation and using precise wording :)